# How can I conditionally change the values in a numpy array taking into account nans?

Tags: python, numpy

My array is a 2D matrix and it has `numpy.nan` values besides negative and positive values:

```
>>> array
array([[        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., -0.04891211,
                nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       ..., 
       [-0.02510989, -0.02520096, -0.02669156, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       [-0.02725595, -0.02715945, -0.0286231 , ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan]], dtype=float32)
```

(There are positive numbers in the array, they just don't show in the preview.)

And I want to replace all the positive numbers with a number and all the negative numbers with another number.

How can I perform that using python/numpy?

(For the record, the matrix is a result of geoimage, which I want to perform a classification)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The fact that you have `np.nan` in your array should not matter. Just use fancy indexing:

```
x[x>0] = new_value_for_pos
x[x<0] = new_value_for_neg
```

If you want to replace your `np.nans`:

```
x[np.isnan(x)] = something_not_nan
```

More info on fancy indexing [a tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2) and the [NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: It would be better if there were a single transformation, because your approach doesn't work if e.g. `new_value_for_pos < 0`.

Comment: @oulenz I posted [an answer about that](/a/74175287/4518341)

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
a[a>0] = 1
a[a<0] = -1
```

Answer (score 3):

to add or subtract to current value then (np.nan not affected)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(-10, 10).reshape((4, 5))

print("after -")
print(a)

a[a<0] = a[a<0] - 2
a[a>0] = a[a>0] + 2


print(a)
```

output

```
[[-10  -9  -8  -7  -6]
 [ -5  -4  -3  -2  -1]
 [  0   1   2   3   4]
 [  5   6   7   8   9]]

after -

[[-12 -11 -10  -9  -8]
 [ -7  -6  -5  -4  -3]
 [  0   3   4   5   6]
 [  7   8   9  10  11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424896/4518341) doesn't work if `new_value_for_pos` is negative. In that case, you could use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in a chain:

```
# Example values
x = np.array([np.nan, -0.2, 0.3])
new_value_for_pos = -1
new_value_for_neg = 2

x[:] = np.where(x>0, new_value_for_pos, np.where(x<0, new_value_for_neg, x))
```

Result:

```
array([nan,  2., -1.])
```

Comment: P.S. I have the feeling there's an easier way to do this, but I'm not sure what

Comment: Another option would be to save `lt = x<0` first then do `x[lt] = new_value_for_neg`, but then you're left with another array. Hmm... Maybe packaging it in a function could be cleaner, so the other array gets cleaned up automatically.