# how to reset every value in a 2d numpy array to either 0, or the max value in the array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array populated with many integers, example: from 0-9.  How do I efficiently reset any value that is less than 9 to 0, leaving only the 9s?

The max value won't *always* be 9, so it will need to use `np.amax(array)` or similar to define the max value before parsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can i conditionally change the values in a numpy array taking into account nan numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424824/how-i-can-i-conditionally-change-the-values-in-a-numpy-array-taking-into-account)

Comment: `ar[ar<9] = 0`?

Answer (score 0):

`array[array < 9] = 0` solves it, thanks to @Masoud